# How to handle complex business logic for permissions

Tags: sql-server, software-design

I have a system in development and part of the system is how permissions are handled, business logic rules for this are very complex so after lots of trials, we couldn't fit them directly in the database and I came up with the following model (the structure is very simplified of course):

```
Table [OperationType]
Id    | Name
--------------
1     | View
2     | Edit
3     | Delete
4     | Create

Table [Permission]
Id    | Name    | OperationType_Id    | Condition/Scope
--------------------------------------------------------

Table [Role]
Id    | Name
-------------

Table [Role_Permission]
Id    | Role_Id    | Permission_Id
----------------------------------

Table [User]
Id    | Name
-------------

Table [Entity]

Id    | Name
-------------
```

Permissions are basically View/Edit/Delete/Create entities with specific criteria
The problem is that the permissions are usually very complex and cannot be translated directly to where conditions for select statements, so evaluating them for every request in case of millions of records in the database (especially for View/Edit/Delete permissions) is very expensive operation and takes a lot of times, so I came up with the following table to translate the business rules into:

```
Table [UserEntityOperationType]
Id    | User_Id    | Entity_Id    | OperationType_Id
-----------------------------------------------------
```

and this table is updated automatically by the back end with certain triggers (ex, new entity is created, user has been assigned a new role and such triggers)

I was told that this design is a bad design, so my questions are:

1. Is this design model a known model? If yes, What is the name of it? and any readings about it are much appreciated.
2. What are the pros and cons of this design mode?
3. If this design is really bad and have lots of cons vs pros, what are the alternatives of designing a system with such complicated business rules?

**Edit:**

To make things more clear, below are some examples of the system authorization requirements:

- We have three object types (line [Entity] table above), let them be [Entity], [Project], [Object3]
- Each of those object types is linked to the other two using link tables.
- For each of those object types, we have a manager, and creator.
- For each of those object types, we have parent-child relationship using [Parent_Id] column.

If there's a page that lists projects that the user can see, those are some conditions that projects must match any of them:

- Projects where the user is creator.
- Projects where an entity he is the manager of, is linked to.
- Projects where an Object3 he is the manager of, is linked to.
- Projects where any of the employees in the entities he manages, is the creator or manager.
- Child projects of all projects he can see (Recursively).

**Edit**

The technology used is N-tier application (DAL, API, MVC UI), in the UI for example, we have a page that lists projects that the user can see, from there can do actions of those projects

Comment: While i did post a answer, you should give more details about the frontend used and whether you use entity frameork, mvc, etc..

Answer (score 0):

One big optimization you can make is to create a sessionPermissions table. On user logon you would write those permissions so they are not evaluated for every query you run.

The biggest security problem with your approach is that the user connecting to the server will have sql access to all the tables(most probably will be db_owner). So if someone finds your connectionstring and access to the server, they can read *all* the data in your database, completely bypassing your security.

Depending on the app you develop, sometimes you need row-level filtering (e.g. see only a part of the table rows). I don't see any plan for that in your question.

What basicly makes me feel uneasy is that this approach tries to impose business logic restrictions in the data layer, not in the business layer, and it will cause issues later.

In my work, we have much of our business logic in stored procedures.

So one approach(if your frontend allows it) would be to create stored procedures(SP from now on) and only grant access to those, not to the tables themselves. Each SP would call a validation SP that would basicly check if the user has the rights based on the context (each SP would require the user to have certain roles in order to run).

If you need to also filter rows based on access rights, you could have a column in each table that stores the access right needed to read/change data.

In order to have a better answer, you need to give us more details about what kind of app this is and what technologies are used in the frontend / middleware, as there is no 'one way' of doing things.

Comment: I have the impression that there's a misunderstanding in my question and that your answer is not related to it, what I'm asking for is how to handle the user authorization on the UI level, and how to store those rules in the database, the use have no access at all to the database it self.